# Is it always the case that I can split limits like this when they exist?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I was working on a limit problem thing-a-ma-bob when I happened to wonder the following question:

> Is it always the case that $$\lim_{h\to a}f(x(h),y(h))=\lim_{u\to a}\lim_{v\to a}f(x(u),y(v))=\lim_{v\to a}\lim_{u\to a}f(x(u),y(v))$$ when they exist?

That is, I was wondering if having the limit exist is enough to have them all equal.  Intuitively, it seems that it should be the case, but I'm not entirely sure about this.

Comment: See the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit  You need uniform convergence in one of the variables.

Comment: @RJTK Ah, thank you.  I was wondering what the term was :-(